# Not able to add TestNG library in Eclipse java build path

Tags: eclipse, testng, buildpath

Not able to add TestNG library in Eclipse java build path. I have installed/uninstalled multiple times but still not able to get TestNG under "Run As". When I look under installed software, it shows TestNG there but no where else it's listed like Add Library and other places. Please help.

I am using Eclipse Neon. TestNG 6.13.0.

Comment: Have u installed the testng plugin? https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/

Comment: It is working fine now. I just changed testNG  plugin from 6.14.3 to 6.9.11